# Первое android приложение с доступом к серверу

Tags: android

Есть сервер на php, на котором написано: Привет Мир! Как создать приложение android, чтобы он обратился к серверу и вывел это?

Comment: @Seth, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно послать get запрос на сервер, получить ответ (ту самую преветственную строку) и вывести ее удобным образом (например, в TextView). Сделать get запрос не сложно, есть [даже готовые примеры](http://hayageek.com/android-http-post-get/#get).

Comment: To send HTTP GET request follow the steps.
1. Create an object of HttpClient

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
2. Create an object of HttpGet

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");
3. Finally make HTTP request

HttpResponse response;
try {
    response = client.execute(request);
             
    Log.d("Response of GET request", response.toString());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
Не понял это

Comment: Что нужно сделать? Это в Android Studio? Если да, то в каком месте?

Comment: Я думал, что простенькое приложение Вы умеет создавать (даже не для андроида).  Открывайте сайт [startandroid](http://startandroid.ru/ru/) или подобные и начинайте изучать базу.

А вот куда именно втыкнуть код и как именно втыкнуть в android studio - это будет очень долго объяснять.

Comment: Дело в том что простенькое, отправить запрос на сервер и вывести привет мир! Или что там будет написано

Comment: Тогда формулируйте вопрос правильно, в нем в конце должно быть как минимум так "Мне нужна детальная инструкция, с картинками и желательно видео, а также готовый проект". Но только подобного здесь не очень любят.

Answer (score 0):

Может стоит начать с фреймворка [Kivy](https://kivy.org) (Python) ? Хорош околонулевым порогом входа + мультиплатформенен (удобно отлаживаться и база клиентов не ограничена телефоном/планшетом).

Вот пример из документации по получению данных по HTTP:
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html